# Configuring a custom Gradle sourceSet using a closure

Tags: gradle

I'm trying to develop a Gradle plugin for a language I use (SystemVerilog). I'm still experimenting and figuring things out. Before I write the entire thing as a plugin, I thought it would be best to try out the different parts I need inside a build script, to get a feel of how things should work.

I'm trying to define a container of source sets, similar to how the Java plugin does it. I'd like to be able to use a closure when configuring a source set. Concretely, I'd like to be able to do the following:

```groovy
sourceSets {
    main {
        sv {
            include '*.sv'
        }
    }
}
```

I defined my own `sourceSet` class:

```groovy
class SourceSet implements Named {
    final String name
    final ObjectFactory objectFactory

    @Inject
    SourceSet(String name, ObjectFactory objectFactory) {
        this.name = name
        this.objectFactory = objectFactory
    }

    SourceDirectorySet getSv() {
        SourceDirectorySet sv = objectFactory.sourceDirectorySet('sv',
            'SystemVerilog source')
        sv.srcDir("src/${name}/sv")
        return sv
    }

    SourceDirectorySet sv(@Nullable Closure configureClosure) {
        configure(configureClosure, getSv());
        return this;
    }
}
```

I'm using `org.gradle.api.file.SourceDirectorySet` because that already implements `PatternFilterable`, so it should give me access to `include`, `exclude`, etc.

If I understand the concept correctly, the `sv(@Nullable Closure configureClosure)` method is the one that gives me the ability to write `sv { ... }` to configure via a closure.

To add the `sourceSets` property to the project, I did the following:

```groovy
project.extensions.add("sourceSets",
        project.objects.domainObjectContainer(SourceSet.class))
```

As per the Gradle docs, this should give me the possibility to configure `sourceSets` using a closure. [This site](https://docs.gradle.org/6.7.1/userguide/custom_gradle_types.html#nameddomainobjectcontainer), which details using custom types, states that by using `NamedDomainObjectContainer`, Gradle will provide *a DSL that build scripts can use to define and configure elements*. This would be the `sourceSets { ... }` part. This should also be the `sourceSets { main { ... } }` part.

If I create a `sourceSet` for `main` and use it in a task, then everything works fine:

```groovy
project.sourceSets.create('main')

task compile(type: Task) {
    println 'Compiling source files'
    println project.sourceSets.main.sv.files
}
```

If I try to configure the `main` source set to only include files with the `.sv` extension, then I get an error:

```groovy
sourceSets {
    main {
        sv {
            include '*.sv'
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
No signature of method: build_47mnuak4y5k86udjcp7v5dkwm.sourceSets() is applicable for argument types: (build_47mnuak4y5k86udjcp7v5dkwm$_run_closure1) values: [build_47mnuak4y5k86udjcp7v5dkwm$_run_closure1@effb286]
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I'm sure it's just a simple thing that I'm forgetting. Does anyone have an idea of what that might be?

Comment: I managed to solve it, will post an answer later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was going wrong. It was a combination of poor copy/paste skills and the fact that Groovy is a dynamic language.

First, let's look at the definition of the `sv(Closure)` function again:

```
SourceDirectorySet sv(@Nullable Closure configureClosure) {
    configure(configureClosure, getSv());
    return this;
}
```

Once I moved this code to an own Groovy file and used the IDE to show me what is getting called, I noticed that it wasn't calling the function I expected. I was expecting a call to `org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure`. Since this is part of the public API, I expected it to be imported by default in the build script. As [this page](https://docs.gradle.org/6.7.1/userguide/writing_build_scripts.html#script-default-imports) states, this is not the case.

To solve the issue, it's enough to add the following import:

```
import static org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure
```

This will get rid of the cryptic closure related error. It is replaced by the following error, though:

```
Cannot cast object 'SourceSet_Decorated@a6abab9' with class 'SourceSet_Decorated' to class 'org.gradle.api.file.SourceDirectorySet'
```

This is caused by the copy/paste error I mentioned. When I wrote the `SourceSet` class, I drew heavily from `org.gradle.api.tasks.SourceSet` (and `org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultSourceSet`). If we look at the `java(Closure)` method there, we'll see it has the following signature:

```
SourceSet java(@Nullable Closure configureClosure);
```

Notice that it returns `SourceSet` and not `SourceDirectorySet` like in my code. Using the proper return type fixes the issue:

```
SourceSet sv(@Nullable Closure configureClosure)
```

With this new return type, let's look again at the configuration code for the source set:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        sv {
            include '*.sv'
        }
    }
}
```

Initially, I thought it was supposed to work as follows: pass `main { ... }` as a `Closure` to `sourceSets`, pass `sv { ... }` as a `Closure` to `main`, and handle the `include ...` part inside `sourceDirectorySet`. I banged my head against the wall for a while, because I couldn't find any code in that class hierarchy that takes closures like this.

Now, I think the flow is slightly different: pass `main { ... }` as a `Closure` to `sourceSets` (as initially thought), but call the `sv(Closure)` function on `main` (of type `sourceSet`), passing it `{ include ... }` as the argument.

---

Bonus: There was one more issue that wasn't related to the "compile" errors I was having.

Even after getting the code to run without errors, it still wasn't behaving as expected. I had some files with the `*.svh` extension that were still getting picked up. This is because, when calling `getSv()`, it was creating a new `SourceDirectorySet` each time. Any configuration that was done previously was getting thrown away each time that this function was called.

Making the `sourceDirectorySet` a class member and moving its creation to the constructor fixed the issue:

```
private SourceDirectorySet sv

SourceSet(String name, ObjectFactory objectFactory) {
    // ...
    sv = objectFactory.sourceDirectorySet('sv',
            'SystemVerilog source')
    sv.srcDir("src/${name}/sv")
}

SourceDirectorySet getSv() {
    return sv
}
```